# Ada: How to organise nested packages

Tags: package, structure, ada

Suppose we have a vehicle, which gets its position from an IMU. The IMU package consists of several private components, which it orchestrates to calculate the vehicle's state in space:

```ada
with IMU; use IMU;
Package Vehicle is
...
end vehicle; 

Package IMU is

    type Attitude is record
        Lat, Lon: Angle;
        Pitch, Roll, Yaw: Angle;
        GroundSpeed: Speed;
        ...
    end record
    
    function Get_Position return Attitude is ...
    
    Package GPS is
    ...
    end GPS;
    
    Package Accelerometer is
    ...
    end Accelerometer;
    
    Package Gyro is
    ...
    end Gyro;
end IMU;
```

The internals of GPS, Accelerometer and Gyro only make sense in the context of the IMU; they must be completely hidden from Vehicle.

Declaring the IMU and all of its sub-components in a single source file will be difficult to read and maintain; I'd like to have each sub-component in it's own source file. If I code them all at the IMU level, the vehicle will be able to access the GPS, which is wrong.

What is the best practice for structuring nested packages?

Comment: You can put them in the body of IMU (most hidden), or you can put them in private child packages (not quite as hidden).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to structure your code but instead of using nested packages, I would use a private child for each "component".

This way, each component would be in its own unit and be visible from its parent and its siblings implementations.

Your code would then be

```ada
Package IMU is

    type Attitude is record
        Lat, Lon: Angle;
        Pitch, Roll, Yaw: Angle;
        GroundSpeed: Speed;
        ...
    end record
    
    function Get_Position return Attitude is ...
        
end IMU;

private package IMU.GPS is
    ...
end IMU.GPS;

private package IMU.Accelerometer is
    ...
end IMU.Accelerometer;
    
private package IMU.Gyro is
    ...
end IMU.Gyro;
```

See [the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Packages#Child_packages) for other examples